# Variable declared in __init__() without self

Tags: python

If I declare variable in `__init__` without self, what happens to it. I know it is not class variable or instance variable. what is the exact term to describe it? How can I access it? What impact can it have while creating object of MyClass1.

```
class MyClass1:
    myname = "Class variable"
    def __init__(self):
        myname = "Instance variable???"   #Deliberately declared without self

a = MyClass1()
print(a.myname)
```

Comment: It's a local variable, local to the method `__init__()`. You cannot access it outside of that method and its value is discarded once you leave `__init__()`.

Comment: It's just a local variable, like in any other method or function. Nothing special happens here.

Answer (score 3):

The variable `myname` is local to the `__init__` method. Nothing will happen to the `myname` attribute of `MyClass1`. If you want to change the  value of it, you should use the self.

```
class MyClass1:
    myname = "Class variable"
    def __init__(self):
        self.myname = "my attribute"

a = MyClass1()
print(a.myname)
```